# Sculpting problem

Tags: sculpting

I downloaded a free 3d Blender Character and I wanted to change a little the body and face shape but i can t do anything. When I select a brush it does nothing. What can I do to change it? I am a 3d Modeling beginner.

[image: This is the picture]

Comment: could you please share the file or at least of it? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/